# Украинизмы в русском языке

Tags: заимствования

Интересный момент. Может быть, я не прав, но, по-моему, украинизмы используются в русском языке часто для придания понятию ироничный оттенок. Вот, например, плохие стихи часто называют виршами (по-украински "вiрши" - стихи), кое-как рисовать - малевать ("малювати" - по-украински рисовать) и т.д. Интересно, это случайно?
А еще прочитал интересную вещь, что просторечное "мобилка" произошло тоже из украинского языка или с юга России. Правда ли это?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Интересный момент. Может быть, я не прав, но, по-моему, украинизмы используются в русском языке часто для придания понятию ироничнoго оттенка.

Да ничего интересного. Манера передразнивать чужую речь не ограничивается одним украинским. Но украинский ближе и понятнее всего. Отсюда такое отношение к ближайшему соседу.

> А еще прочитал интересную вещь, что просторечное "мобилка" произошло тоже из украинского языка или с юга России. Правда ли это?

Сомнительно. Зачем далеко ходить, когда есть вполне русские мочалка, колонка, веревка и даже селедка?!

Comment: Точно. Да и "малевать", и "вирши" - тоже не украинизмы. У этих слов общая этимология, далее значения слегка разошлись.

Answer (score -2):

Украинизмы :слова печерский - укр.печера - пещера;
                  повстанцы - повстання  -восстание;
мещанский,мещанин,местечковый -місто     -город.

Comment: Для того, чтобы с полным основанием охарактеризовать слово как украинизмом, одного фонетического сходства явно недостаточно. Надо еще убедиться,что слово заимствовано именно из украинского. Из всех ваших примеров только местечковый с оговоркоами может претендовать на подобное. печера - старослявянизм, повстанцы скорее уж можно принять за полонизм, но реально вполне себе русское, как и "мещанство", "мещанин". "Местечко" - название небольших городков в Польше и Малороссии, часто в контексте черты оседлости. Считать ли само слово заимствованием - не уверен..

Comment: Вот еще: укр. село - деревня, Світ,світський -мир,светский.  А термин "малоросия" -это обозначение метрополии, как Малая Польша, Малая Греция, Малая Италия, -большие территории- это колонии.